# Does This Qualify As A Split Pot?

Tags: nlhe, rules, reading-hands

My partner and I are fighting about this.
I had 10 and something, don't remember and he had 3 and 2.
On the table : 10 J Q K A.
I think I win with my 10 completing my straight but he said we had to split cause it was straight in the table.
Who is right in this case guys?
Thank you!

Comment: Unless one of you has a flush, the pot is split. He's got a 10 is his hand too--right there on the board.

Answer (score 12):

It's a split.

In short, the best 5 card hand that you can make wins. In this case, you're both playing the board.

There is a similar question here, [What is the“Top Five Cards” rule and how does it apply to splitting pots?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/402/88), explaining the scenario in more detail.

Comment: Why should I split if I have a connection and he doesn't? For my logic it's wrong.

Comment: I already read it but it's not the same.

Comment: Community cards can be used by all players, thus your connection doesn't matter. Only the relative ranking of a players qualifying hand. As for the logic of it all, it's a man-made game, so if anything, the rules are arbitrary.

Comment: @Anna The rules say the best 5 card hand is played. The fact that you have an extra 10 is immaterial by rule. The term counterfeited often applies in these cases where you have a made hand and cards come that nullify cards in your hand.

Comment: Basically you both have 7 cards of which to make the best 5 card hand. Thats 2 personal cards and 5 common cards. In this case the best hand possibly consisted of all 5 common cards (the 2 cards in each of your hands could be ripped up and thrown away), thus its a split pot. 
If your card made it a royal flush then you would win, however I guess that was not the case, so it was a draw.