# Split staight between players

Tags: texas-hold-em, reading-hands

i need some help

there were on the table staight - 8,9,10,J,Q 
i had J and Q and the other player had 7 and A

is this split ?

thanks

Comment: You could've tried googling the answer for 2 minutes... did you ?

Comment: Question closed because there was no proven research effort on the part of the asker.

Comment: @RaduMurzea Very rude.

Comment: Hi @user1693, Poker.SE is a good place to find out this stuff. Use the search box at the top the site first to see if your question has already been asked by someone else. In this case, using the search term "split pot" yielded at least two decent results, [Does This Qualify As A Split Pot?](http://poker.stackexchange.com/q/1111/88) & [What is the“Top Five Cards” rule and how does it apply to splitting pots?](http://poker.stackexchange.com/q/402/88). If you can't find the answers you need, please create your own question. I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes this is a split, since you always count the 5 best cards out of board cards + hand cards.

you would have a street from board and your other 2 cards don't care if they don't help to upgrade that street. IF you had a king, you would have won here.