# Who wins the pot when

Tags: texas-hold-em

We dealt the cards and this is what happened :

- my brother had 5 3
- And I had 7 5

The board is 5 10 9 9 3.

Who wins the pot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the"Top Five Cards" rule and how does it apply to splitting pots?](http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/402/what-is-thetop-five-cards-rule-and-how-does-it-apply-to-splitting-pots)

Comment: oh sure, close another one..

Answer (score 3):

It is a split pot. You both have the same hand.

Both of you have 5,5,10,9,9

See the [5 card rule](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/402/what-is-thetop-five-cards-rule-and-how-does-it-apply-to-splitting-pots?rq=1).

Comment: I would say you both have "9, 9, 5, 5, 10", but yeah, split pot.