# What happens if there is royal flush on board

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

Will the high card rule apply or chips would be split?

Is this the same with other nuts combination like AK full house, 10-A straight and four of a kind?

Comment: Best 5 cards every time.  http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/402/what-is-thetop-five-cards-rule-and-how-does-it-apply-to-splitting-pots

Comment: There is no such thing as a "high card rule". The _only_ thing that matters is the best 5 cards, and if they happen to be in the window, then everyone has them and their pocket cards are 100% irrelevant.

Comment: Yesterday playing at Seminole Hard Rock, just me at the table $20 bet, Texas Holden pokers, the dealer through on the board the Royal flush, I just betting $5.00 on the trips and I just get paid $250.00, I’m still confused, it was the right paid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best five cards play, so the remaining players at showdown split the pot.

In the case of a full house, if somebody has a better pair in their hand or make of 4 of a kind the best 5 card hand wins.  If there are 4 of a kind on the board, the highest fifth card wins.

I flopped a full house once. Nines full of sevens.  I lost when the turn and river both had sevens, counterfeiting my hand.  I lost to Ax.

Comment: Note: For four of a kind, the highest fifth card could also be on the board in which case its a tie again. For instance 2222A on the board will always result in a tie, even if someone else has an Ace too.

Comment: Just for future readers, I had trouble imagining this situation, so I've written it out: So say you had AB and the board goes CDE-7-7, then ABCDE has 99977 collectively. If CDE=999 then you have AB=77 so you'd have quad 7s, so you'd only lose to another 9. If CDE=997 then you had AB=77 but there can't be 5 7's so this case is impossible. If CDE=977 then you had AB=99, in which case you'd lose to Ax because you both had quad 7s while Villain's A kicker beats your 9 kicker.

Comment: @BenjaminWang sorry I didn't make that clearer.  I had 99 and flopped 977. Turn and river were sevens. Puting four of a kind sevens on the board with a 9.  My oponent had the better kicker withan Ace in his hand. That hand still stings almost 10 years later.

Answer (score 2):

Every player plays the best 5-card hand he can make. If that's the five on the board, then that's what he plays. If nobody can beat the 5-card hand on the board, then the pot is split. This happens most often when the board is A-K-Q-J-10, with no three of a suit. No one can have any hand higher than the Broadway, so they split. Same with a Royal, or if the board is quads with an ace. If the board were, say, a K-high straight flush, a player with the ace in his hand would win with a royal. If the board has, say, 33337, then anyone with a card higher than the 7 can pay that as their fifth card, and the highest one wins (likely 2 or 3 will split the pot with an ace). If the board is AAAKK, a player with the 4th ace can play AAAAK. A player with KK in his hand can play KKKKA.

It should be noted that it's important that players not call attention to this situation in play. I remember dealing a board of 5555A once. One player bet, and two folded! No one said anything, which is exactly the way it should be. The bettor is entitled to take advantage of the ignorance of the folders without anyone else educating them.