# Five cards rule and "kicker" in flush

Tags: learning, hand

Scenario:

My hand: A3
Villain: KQ
Flop: J76

Maybe a stupid question: considering all cards with same suit, my ace wins the pot or other higher cards can affect the result?

Comment: The ace wins the pot.  You pick the best 5 cards and ignore the rest.  Ace high flush will always beat a king high flush.  Duplicate of [http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/402/what-is-thetop-five-cards-rule-and-how-does-it-apply-to-splitting-pots](http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/402/what-is-thetop-five-cards-rule-and-how-does-it-apply-to-splitting-pots)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It aint over till the river.   If T9 suited come up then you lose to a straight flush.

Otherwise you win with a higher flush.  An ace high flush is called the nut flush.  But it would still lose to a full house, four or a kind, or a straight flush.

When it is part of made part of the hand you don't call it a kicker. It is an ace high flush or king high straight.  When the made part is not 5 cards then you have a kicker - pair of queens with an ace kicker.

[Poker Hand Ranking](http://www.pokerology.com/charts/poker-hand-rankings.pdf)