# Who will win, 2 pairs on the table or one pair in hand and one pair on the table?

Tags: rules, hand

Table: 7, 7, 6, 6, 4
Me: 5, 4
Opponent: 9, 8
Who  wins?

Comment: But this is not duplicate.    This is not a split pot.  This has a kicker.  The duplicate does not have a kicker.   This site needs a good answer on order of hands rather than a narrow *catch all*.

Comment: @Frisbee The suggested question to review, and many subsequent answers definitely cover the concept required to answer this question. The concept is the stated here as the "Top Five Card" rule. It applies to this case too. To Tatiana, check it out. You'll find what you're looking for there.

Comment: @TobyBooth Cool  but the link does not address two pair. Based on "concept"  I don't get how a full house question http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6673/full-house-highest-trip-or-card would not be a dup.  It is just a polite feedback - not meant to criticize.

Comment: @Frisbee Personally, & particularly at this stage of the sites development, it's a flexible policy. I'll try to explain my reasoning. If a question is from a newer user, is well formatted, is a little different from other similar Q's in terms of content, I often decide to leave it open. I'd like these new users to gain some reputation points, get their answer, & continue to use the site more in the future. Closing all duplicate Q's doesn't seem productive in that sense. In the future, better more comprehensive answers will inevitably rise beyond these types of Q's. It's an evolving process.

Comment: @Frisbee RE: your Two Pair comment, [this](http://poker.stackexchange.com/a/405/88) answer covers that possibility. "Top five cards" as a rule covers EVERY possibility. Obviously this example is Texas hold 'em. Other games will vary. If it's still not clear, and you don't think there is a definitive answer... or question about this, please write one up :)

Comment: @TobyBooth If "Top five cards" as a rule covers EVERY possibility" then it cover full house.  No need to get confrontational.  You got my input.

Answer (score 3):

Best 5 cards every time

Your 4 does not play because it is lower than the 2 pair on the table

You:  7, 7, 6, 6, 5

Opponent : 7, 7, 6, 6, 9

You lose because your opponent has a higher kicker

If the board was J, 7, 7, 6, 6 you both would have played the board and it would be a tie = split the pot

[WIKI list of poker hands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands)

Answer (score 0):

Either the pair in hand (if that is bigger than at least one of the community pairs) or if it is smaller than both of them, the 5th card will come into play.

So, your opponent by 5th card "9" wins in the scenario given.