# Full House..highest trip or card?

Tags: nlhe, rules

Eg: if player 1 has 444 full of AA and player 2 has 888 and 44 , which is best hand , highest card or highest trips ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands

Answer (score 2):

The winner is the player with the highest trips, so 88844 is the winning hand.

If you use the search term "Full House" then you should find a few more decent examples here to explain the concept.

Also, check out the "five card rule" for a definitive overview of Texas Hold Em hand rankings.

Answer (score 1):

**The winner is always the best 5-card hand. So, in the case of a Full House, it goes by the 3-of-a-kind first, then the pair.**

444AA vs.88844
888 is higher than 444, so ‘88844’ is the high hand here. The only time the pair matters is if both players have the same 3-of-a-kind. For example:

444AA vs. 44488 (444 is on the board, Player 1 has pocket AA, Player 8 has pocket 88).
Since both players share the 444, the tie-breaker is the pair they use. AA beats 88, so Player 1 would win here having 444AA as their best 5-card hand.