# Can some tell me which hand(s) beats the dealers hand in this game of poker?

Tags: rules, learning

Dealers hand: 
2 diamonds, 5 diamonds, 8 diamonds, Jack diamonds,and King diamonds

1st hand: 2 spades, 2 hearts, 3 diamonds, 9 clover, and 10 hearts.

2nd hand: 3 spades, 3 hearts, 4 clover, Queen clover, and King spades.

3rd hand: 10 spades, Jack hearts, Queen Spades, King Hearts, and 3 Clovers.

4th hand: Ace diamonds, Ace clover, Ace heart, 9 spade, and 9 diamonds.

5th hand: 5 clovers, 6 hearts, 8 hearts, 10 diamonds, and Jack clover.

6th hand: 4 spades, 6 clovers, 8 clovers, 9 hearts, and Queen diamonds.

7th hand: 4 diamonds, 4 hearts, 5 spades, 8 spades, and King clover.

8th hand: 7 clover, 7 diamonds, 7 spade, 2 clover, and 10 clover

Comment: Every clover was out.

Comment: @Paparazzi I think for these type of questions, [What is the“Top Five Cards” rule and how does it apply to splitting pots?](http://poker.stackexchange.com/q/402/88) provides a better, more succinct answer.

Comment: @TobyBooth I don't agree.  This is not even a top 5 issue.  Each player has 5 cards.  That link does not state a full house beats a flush.  It does not identify a flush or full house.  It is NOT an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Dealer's hand is flush, K-J-8-5-2. 4th hand (winner) is a full house, aces over nines. Dealer beats everything else given.

4th hand: Full House - Wins
A⋄A♣A♥9⋄9♠

Dealer: Flush - Second
2⋄5⋄8⋄J⋄K⋄