# My poker question is about straight and another pair

Tags: hand

we played poker and on the table , 2-2-ace-3-4 and player one five and four player two five and six . who won ? please

Comment: There are multiple threads on this site that describe how hand ranking works in Holdem. As a new user here, Can I ask why you felt compelled to create a question, rather than use a pre-existing Q&A? I ask you as we're often attempting to redirect people to those questions, but I'm not certain how effective that is. Thanks.

Comment: Here are some examples, http://poker.stackexchange.com/q/402/88 & http://poker.stackexchange.com/q/6680/88... Are they what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Player 2 has a higher straight, 2 3 4 **5 6**.

Player 1 has a lower straight, Ace 2 3 **4 5**.

Thus, Player 2 wins.

Comment: Not closing the question.  Toby, are you getting soft?

Comment: You're assumption is mistaken. Generally I only ever close them when someone else suggests it, as my record would show. Also, I'm interested to hear @Mir 's thoughts as a new user.