# Do kickers play when the nut straight is on the board?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

In texas holdem, if there are two players left in the game and the five cards on the table make a straight T J Q K A, and you have a jack in your hand would you win because you didn't need the table jack or would it be a split pot?

Answer (score 2):

Provided there is no flush possible, it's a split pot - both players have the same best 5-card hand of `T J Q K A`.There are no other cards any player can have in Holdem which would improve their hand.

There is an existing question on this site about [the top five cards rule and how it applies to splitting pots](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/402/what-is-thetop-five-cards-rule-and-how-does-it-apply-to-splitting-pots), as well as one on [how to determine the winning hand in poker](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker), both of which probably answer your question in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

To add onto the answer already given, there is no such thing as hand precedence. Just like there are no trump suits, your hole cards are not any more valuable than those on the table. You simply make the best 5 card hand out of the 7 available. It does not matter if you have more than one way to construct the best hand, as all cards of the same value are equivalent.