# Question for beginners in Omaha

Tags: omaha

```
Player 1: Ks 10d 6h 7h

Player 2: 4s 4h Qs Jh
```

Board:

```
As Ad 8s Kh Ah
```

Who is the winner?

Comment: If you search for the "best five card" rule on this site, here(https://poker.stackexchange.com/a/451/88) or elsewhere you'll find this answer readily available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In omaha you must use 2 cards from your hand and 3 cards from the board to make your 5 card poker hand. In this case player 1 will have AAAKT, so three of a kind. Player 2 will have AAA44, which is a full house. Player 2 wins.