# Two pair on the table. Does a lower pair on hand beat an ace kicker?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, hand

The flop was Q, Q, 10, 10, 3.
I have A, K and my friend has 3, 9.

I thought I won with my ace high card because his pair of threes does not beat any of the pairs on the table. Since it is a 5 card game the cards in play would be two queens and two 10s with my ace high.

He claims his pair of 3's trump my ace high card because he has the pair in his hand when my cards in my hand don't have any pairs just the ace high card.

Comment: you are right, the two pair on the table plays and your ace high is a better kicker than his 9. Your 5-card hand would be QQTTA and his is QQTT9. reference your friend to this question: https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/402/what-is-thetop-five-cards-rule-and-how-does-it-apply-to-splitting-pots

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you are right and the other player is wrong. Period.  There is no such thing as "three pair" in poker.  Your Ace kicker kicks - simple as that.  However, I've seen some silly house rules that are IMHO stupid.  Where they claiming that this was some house rule?  All that being said, if the rest of the table and/or game host supported the other guy where his "three pair" somehow wins over your Ace kicker - cash out your chips, leave that game and NEVER PLAY WITH THEM AGAIN - THEY CHEAT and/or are IDIOTS.  Either way - run, run away!!!!!!!